# if else python function call or method call

Tags: python, function, if-statement, methods

Can we have call methods based on if elif else... example:

```
if line2[1] = '1': 
    a(line2) 
elif line2[1] = '2': 
    b(line2) 
elif line2[1] = '3': 
    c(line2)
```

and the list goes on. 
Can we use maps and call the function. Say

Example of line inputs:

line = ['1','say','Hi']

line = ['2','How','Are']

Code:

```
def g(line)
   my_map = { '1': a(line),
           '2': b(line),
           '3': c(line, b),
           ......
           and the list goes on
           }
```

---

```
   here if line[0] = '1' call a(line)
        elif line[0] = '2' call b(line)
```

How do I call function based on the input .

Please send example code if possible

Thanks
Rakesh

---

line = ['1','say','Hi','','','','','','',....goes on 5-15 times]
In the same example as above, If I have to assign other variables also. How do I do it.

```
if line2[1] == '8':
             p.plast = line2[3]
             p.pfirst = line2[4]
             p.pid = line2[9]

elif line2[1] == 'I':
             p.slast = line2[3]
             p.sfirst = line2[4]
             p.sid = line2[9]
 elif line2[1] == 'Q':
            p.tlast = line2[3]
             p.tfirst = line2[4]
             p.tid = line2[9]
```

Is there a work around for this too.

Comment: Instead of adding a wrapping function `g`, you can have a function-valued dictionary. If you need to pass some default arguments, as in the case of `3`, you can use a `lambda`.

Comment: Line is sent as a variable to this function. g(line) is called from other place. . Can you send me an example, Please. I am new to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: A tricky method

```
def make_change(line, p):

    # Each value of the dict will be another dict in form property:index.
    # Where property is key of p object to be set/updated, index is index of line with which property should be updated.

    another_map = {
        "V": {'vlast': 3, 'vfirst': 5, 'vnone': 7},
        "S": {'slast':2, 'sfirst':9, 'snone':4}
    }

    val = another_map.get(line[1], None)
    if val is not None:
        # iterating over val items to get which property to set and index if line to set
        for key, item in val.iteritems():
            p[key] = line[item]

    print p


new_list = ["V", "S", 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
make_change(new_list, {})
```

Now change `new_list[1]` end see the output

---

```
if line2[1] = '1': 
    a(line2) 
elif line2[1] = '2': 
    b(line2) 
elif line2[1] = '3': 
    c(line2)
```

Will works perfectly.

But your second method will not work because when you write `my_map = { '1': a(line), ... }`, `my_map['1']` will be `None` or return value of the function(because you are calling the function)

Try this

```
def g(line):
    # Note that value of dict is only the name of the function.
    my_dict = {
      '1': a,
      '2': b
      ...
    }

   # Assuming line[0] is 1,2,3, etc. Check if corresponding function exists in map_dict 
   # Convert line[0] to string before passing it in dict.get() method
   call_func = my_dict.get(str(line[0]), None)
   if call_func is not None:
        call_func(line)
```

Comment: p is an object called from other place. line2 = ['I', 'PO BOX 28082','VISION'] a_map = { 'I': "id", 'S': "sn", '4': "commercial", } setattr(p, a_map[line2[1]], line2[2]) I am sucesfull in executing this code. But how will I assign say if line2[0] == 'I': p.id = line2[1] p.address = line2[1] . # not part of map p.status = line2[2] # not part of map. As you see i cannot assign it in map as it is not part of map. Please explain with example if possible. Thanks –

Comment: sorry i didn't understood `But how will I assign say if line2[0] == 'I': p.id = line2[1] p.address = line2[1] . # not part of map p.status = line2[2] # not part of map. As you see i cannot assign it in map as it is not part of map` correctly! Can you edit your question with some more details ?

Comment: I edited the main question. Let me know if I am not clear there also. Thanks

Comment: @HyderTom updated, let me know if it solves the problem

Comment: I am getting this warning when I typed iteritems().
I am using python 3.6 and Pycharm 
 dict.iterkeys(), dict.iteritems() and dict.itervalues() methods are not available in py3 less... (⌘F1) 
# Enable this inspection if you need your code to be compatible with a range of Python versions 
# The range of Python versions with which the code needs to be compatible can be specified in the inspection settings.
#  Unresolved attribute reference 'iteritems' for class 'dict' less... (⌘F1)

Comment: # This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. 
# Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. 
# Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items.

Comment: Use `items()` instead of `iteritems()`. Iteritems is for python2.x, items() is for 3.x

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but you are slightly wrong -- you should be passing a function object, instead of calling it.

```
def g(line):
    my_map = {'1': a, '2': b, '3': c ... }
    cur_func = my_map.get(line)
    if cur_func is not None:
         cur_func(line)
    else:
         #No mapping found ..
```

Comment: p is an object called from other place. 

line2 = ['I', 'PO BOX 28082','VISION']

a_map = {
            'I': "empolyer_id",
            'S': "sn",
            '4': "commercial",
        }
        setattr(p, a_map[line2[1]], line2[2])

I am sucesfull in executing this code. But how will I assign say 

if line2[0] == 'I'

Comment: p is an object called from other place. 

line2 = ['I', 'PO BOX 28082','VISION']

a_map = {
            'I': "id",
            'S': "sn",
            '4': "commercial",
        }
        setattr(p, a_map[line2[1]], line2[2])

I am sucesfull in executing this code. 

But how will I assign say 

if line2[0] == 'I':

   p.id = line2[1]
  p.address = line2[1] . # not part of map
 p.status = line2[2] # not part of map. As you see i cannot assign it in map  as it is not part of map. Please explain with example if possible. Thanks